# Unable to change WordPress preview post link (with preview_post_link)

Tags: php, wordpress, next.js, headless

I'm doing headless wordpress setup. My frontend is React/NextJS hosted and accessible with example.com and my CMS is accessible with cms.example.com. Now, my preview feature will not work as is so I built my custom WP preview feature and it's available under main domain (example.com).

I tried to write following code to change my preview URL, but it doesn’t seem to be working. Maybe my functions.php is not being executed? Your help will hugely appreciated.

file I modified `/wp-content/themes/theme/functions.php` and added this in the bottom.

```
add_filter('preview_post_link', function ($link) {
        global $post;
        $post_ID = $post->post_parent;
        return 'https://new.url'
                . '/api/preview?id='
                . $post_ID . '&secret=secret';
});
```

Comment: I tried this solution and it is working fine por published posts, but it is not being fired when previewing draft post (which is exactly what I need)

Comment: It seems that it's working ok on posts list page, but not on Gutenberg editor. I could find a useful workaround for this use case [here](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/13998)